# Panoramic render cuts at top

Tags: panoramic

hello im trying build a scene of a street at i have a huge object on the top, im rendering this in panoramic, equirectangular. The thing that happens is that in the viewport its ok but when i render it or i look thru the camera in rendering mode the top part gets cut.

images

[image: Rendering mode viewport]

[image: Camera view rendering mode in panoramic]

Answer (score 1):

Check you Active Camera (Render Camera) Clipping Plane Near and Far. Viewport is not the same as final render Near and Far clipping plane.